# Error Magento 1.9 - You cannot define a correlation name 'ce' more than once

Tags: php, magento

I am facing the following error after installing new theme,

There has been an error processing your request
You cannot define a correlation name 'ce' more than once

Trace:

```
#0 /var/www/html/mage/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', 'catalog_product...', 'ce.entity_id=e....', NULL, NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/mage/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(357): Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', 'catalog_product...', 'ce.entity_id=e....', NULL, NULL)
#2 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/community/Cybage/Marketplace/Block/Catalog/Product/List.php(53): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft('catalog_product...', 'ce.entity_id=e....', NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(120): Cybage_Marketplace_Block_Catalog_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
#4 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/local/Magentothem/Layerednavigationajax/controllers/CategoryController.php(65): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->getLoadedProductCollection()
#5 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Magentothem_Layerednavigationajax_CategoryController->viewAction()
#6 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#7 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/html/mage/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /var/www/html/mage/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

Error log record number: 670450388037

Comment: This is a programming question section => magento.stackexchange exists for administrative type Magento questions. Is this 1) A Magento error out of the blue, 2) A Magento error from a third party module you installed or 3) a Module you created that is throwing an exception error? 1 belongs in magento.stackexchange, 2 needs to be asked with your module developer, it's their responsibility to fix, and 3 needs some samples of your programming code that is causing the issue. Apparently you are asking a 2 type question => as Cybage/Marketplace and Magentothem/Layerednavigationajax indicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your new theme also includef at least one module -- this is a common thing.  This module (`Magentothem_Layerednavigationajax`) has rewritten the main controller for this particular request.  The controller action likely has some custom functionality.

It all appears you have a second module on your system (`Cybage_Marketplace`).  This module appears to rewrite a core product list block with its own `Cybage_Marketplace_Block_Catalog_Product_List` class.

The programming problem here is it appears both your theme and this second module (or possibly some other code, unseen in your stack trace) has tried to add a join to the product collection query using the table alias `ce`.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I commented the following code in config.xml of Cybage marketplace extension and its working fine

<catalog>
                <rewrite> 
                   <product_list>Cybage_Marketplace_Block_Catalog_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
             </catalog>